# Complex Roots (Numerical Methods)

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods

I was given the following question in my Numerical Method exam and I think it is related to Newton's Basis Polynomial, but couldn't solve it. Could anyone guide me to the solution?

Show that for pairwise distinct $x_i$ with $i = 0,1,....,n$ the polynomials

$$P_k(x) = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} x -x_i,  k=0,1,....,n$$

form a basis of the space of polynomials of order n.

Comment: They are linearly independent because they have different degrees and none of them are the zero polynomial. Why do they span the polynomials of degree $n$?

Comment: Small detail: when $k=0$ the formula for $P_k$ is not valid. You would need to define $P_0$ to be a constant for it to be a complete basis.

Comment: Is it like, I have to solve for a_i, with the help of lower triangular matrix and show there are at most a_n??

Comment: That is one way to do it. You don't need to explicitly solve for $a_i$, just show that there always is a solution. What can you say about the diagnal elements of the lower triangular matrix (using that the $x_i$'s are distinct) and what does this tell you about the determinant of the matrix?

Comment: @Winther The standard convention is that the empty product is $1$, thus here $P_0(x)=1$.